# Removing object from scene in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am digging the documentation to see if there's a remove method, I just get this link whenever I google 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/580998/JavaFX/java/remove-node

there's a simple remove option 
Eg : .getChildren().remove(object)

It does not seem to work for me !

Comment: Could you please provide us with more information? e.g. source code

Comment: @GGrec, here's the code :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677110/putting-an-object-on-a-stage-when-mouse-clicked/22678406#22678406

Answer (score 1):

The code which you've provided works fine with me.

Add circle with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>, and remove them by simply clicking on them.

The reason I've used the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key for adding the circles is because in the below code, both the scene *and* the circles handle mouse clicks. Thus, the code has to know from where the event is coming from. This is just an example, of course.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ChangeListenerSample extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400,80);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        scene.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override public void handle(final MouseEvent event)
            {
                if (!event.isAltDown())
                    return;

                final Circle circle = new Circle(event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY(),30);
                circle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                root.getChildren().add(circle);

                circle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

                    @Override public void handle(final MouseEvent arg0)
                    {
                        root.getChildren().remove(circle);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```